# Visual force chatter feed based on a topic

Tags: visualforce, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

I have some users that have requested to show chatter based on a hash tag topic rather than an account's ID. Is this possible using standard components or will I have to go crazy with the REST API?

Comment: Do you mean like [viewing details about a particular topic](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_topics.htm)(hash tag)?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the <chatter:feedWitFollowers> tag to show chatter a chatter feed for an account. The users want to see it based on the hashtag topic instead.

Comment: I'd like an easy way of showing it on the visual force page without having to spend a lot of time coding the gathering of data in Apex by searching the Topic table, then search for posts and comments for those topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use the `<chatter:feed>` component in Spring '14. I tried the following in a Winter '14 developer org and it didn't work, but in a Spring '14 sandbox it did. Fortunately Spring '14 is getting released very soon.

```
<chatter:feed entityId="[topic ID]" />
```

Comment: That works but don't use it with <chatter:feedWithFollowers> Internal server error every time. :(

Comment: Yikes, thanks Robert. I've alerted the engineering team about the internal server error, and we'll get it fixed (sorry, don't have an ETA yet).

Comment: I'd love to hear when they get it fixed and if it will be able to support the topic Id too. That would be more useful than just the standard feed component.

Comment: Robert, thanks for finding this.  What do you mean by: "and if it will be able to support the topic Id" ?

Comment: It would be nice if I could have a chatter feed show not only chatter to the object but also be able to have it show chatter to a topic as well. Since I can't put more than one chatter component on a page, I can't show chatter on an object and chatter based on a topic on the same page without coding out the functionality. It would also be nice if the supplied components would automatically show the "Hid Feed" button too.

Comment: Robert, the internal server error issue with <chatter:feedWithFollowers> is scheduled to be fixed in the next patch release. It should be working for you on Thursday, March 13.